# What are the primes of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}\colon \text{$p$ prime}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, prime-factorization

Let $R$ denote subdomain of $\mathbb{C}$ which is isomorphic to the direct limit of the diagram of commutative rings $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3}]\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{-5}]\hookrightarrow\dotsm$.

> What is the set of *primes* of $R$? What is a citable reference (with proof) for this?

Comment: FWIW, it is not even clear to me whether, when given some $a\in R$, deciding whether $a$ is a prime of the ring $R$ can be done in one of the finitely-generated subrings $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p_1},\dotsc,\sqrt{-p_s}]\hookrightarrow R$. (Of course, $p_k$ denotes the $k-th$ prime.)

Comment: This is very complicated. You know of course that $\sqrt6\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3}\,]$. And therefore even this ring has infinitely many units such as $5+2\sqrt6$. So “primes”, by which I presume you mean indecomposable elements, may get pretty hairy, pilose, hirsute.